# Multiple sailsjs applications running on same port

Tags: node.js, sails.js, reverse-proxy

I need to run multiple sails web application on the port and run a small server to route between them by application name.

Using next code, I could route between them by adding application name after the port 3000.

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var app1 = 'http://localhost:1337/',
    app2 = 'http://localhost:1338/'

app.all("/app1/*", function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {target: app1});
});

app.all("/app2/*", function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {target: app2});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This Program make the redirection well but now the problem is that, how i can change the generated links in sailsjs for any file as javascript and css files?
Many thanks

Comment: this is really strange set up. Do you really need to do that this way ? What is your case in full picture ? There has to be better solution

Comment: What i need exactly is to use one port to access different sails applications.
So i can write 
http://localhost:3000/app1 to access app1
or
http://localhost:3000/app2 to access app2
I have created a repository of the case
https://github.com/Islamaim/multiple-sails-applications
the browser cant reach the css, js files

Comment: You did not get what I am asking for. Why you need to run them using the same port?

Comment: Each application will have his individual port locally
But i need access them with port 80 for example specifying the name of the application

Comment: ah, I will post some solution in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install nginx
2. Run your apps on different ports.
3. On Linux `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` (different on Windows, but probably easy to find):

--

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name apps.dev/1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name apps.dev/2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

4. You can access your apps using: `apps.dev/1` or `apps.dev/2`
5. For production you can apply any domain addressed to the server.
6. For local dev just set virtual host to redirect anything from production domain to local nginx.

Comment: Please i have error in this line
         server_name apps.dev/1;

Comment: I found a file called nginx.conf in windows.
Should i delete all its contents
I only added these lines after another server

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html
I can't help too much with that. It should not be hard to use google to find what you are missing. I hope I gave you good idea to solve your issue. If so, please upvote and accept the answer.